# Powershell extract words with special characters

Tags: regex, powershell

I am extracting values from a text file that have switch values. One of the switch values are a mix of uppercase, lowercase, number and punctuation chracters such as

`/N=1$`, `/N=Source1`, `/N=Source`

So far I have tried

`"/N=1$" -match "/N=\w+"`

After the switch value, there is either a new line or white space character `\s`.

There is only one `/N` switch per file.

Comment: Try a simple `/N=\S+` where `\S+` matches one or more non-whitespace characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\w+` will match word characters (i.e. letters, digits or underscores). You might have non-word characters in the switch values, too.

You can use the following regex

```
/N=\S+
```

See the [regex in action](https://regex101.com/r/iL0tG1/1).

The `\S+` matches one or more non-whitespace characters.

Comment: You are welcome. Once I read you only have those switches once per file, I understood that this regex should be safe to use.